# Emacs, python: Run "sudo pip install names" to install

Tags: python, emacs

Emacs 24.5
Python 2.7.12

If I start simple (Hello world) python script from shell - is OK. But if start more difficult script then return error:

```
python myscript.py "some_params"
```

ATTENTION! https://pypi.python.org/pypi/names/ package is requred to randgen human names.

Run "sudo pip install names" to install.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "myscript.py", line 6, in <module>
    import secretary

  File "my_another_script.py", line 5, in <module>
    import names

ImportError: No module named names
```

Comment: Did you try doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the external libraries you are using. **names** in this case is an external library that you need to install to make your script work.

Comment: First need set environment variable to "pip". In my case this is: "d:\Program Files\Python2.7\Scripts\". Install package "names" by : pip install names. And the I success run: python myscript.py "some_params"